# Chained Transitions in D3.js (force layout)

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I need to create a data visualization which changes the colors of the relevant objects(circles) one after another. And when all circles have been animated to start at the first object again.

Like: change color to green -> delay -> change color back to grey -> animate next object

My current status is here to find: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arssen/vb2fagd3/1/)

```
var test = [9, 8, 2056, 3080, 3084, 1575948, 1575946, 1575947, 1575939, 1576643,
    1576899, 1576931, 1708003, 2039779, 2064355, 2097123, 2097091, 2097107, 2097115,
    2097114, 2097098, 2097099, 2064329, 12233, 4041, 3657, 2057]

var links = [

    {source: 9, target: 8, type: "licensing"},

    {source: 8, target: 3080, type: "licensing"},
    {source: 8, target: 2056, type: "resolved"},

    {source: 3080, target: 3084, type: "licensing"},

    {source: 3084, target: 1575948, type: "licensing"},
    {source: 3084, target: 1051660, type: "resolved"},

    {source:1575948, target: 1575946, type: "licensing"},
    {source:1575948, target: 1575944, type: "resolved"},

    {source:1575946, target: 1575947, type: "licensing"},
    {source:1575946, target: 1575939, type: "resolved"},

    {source:1575947, target: 1575939, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1575939, target: 1576067, type: "licensing"},
    {source:1575939, target: 1576643, type: "resolved"},

    {source:1576067, target: 1576579, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1576067, target: 1576899, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1576067, target: 1576643, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576579, target: 1576899, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1576579, target: 1576643, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576899, target: 1576931, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576931, target: 1708003, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1708003, target: 2039779, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1708003, target: 2064355, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1708003, target: 1777635, type: "licensing"},
    {source:1708003, target: 2056163, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2039779, target: 2064355, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2064355, target: 2097123, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097123, target: 2097091 , type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097091, target: 2097107, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097107, target: 2097115, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097115, target: 2097114, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097114, target: 2097098, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097098, target: 2097099, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097099, target: 2064331, type: "licensing"},
    {source:2097099, target: 2064329, type: "resolved"},
    {source:2097099, target: 2097097, type: "resolved"},

    {source:2064331, target: 12235, type: "resolved"},
    {source:2064331, target: 4043, type: "resolved"},
    {source:2064331, target: 1015755, type: "resolved"},
    {source:2064331, target: 2064329, type: "licensing"},

    {source:12235, target: 4043, type: "licensing"},

    {source:4043, target: 4041, type: "licensing"},


    {source:4041, target: 3785, type: "licensing"},
    {source:4041, target: 2057, type: "resolved"},
    {source:4041, target: 3593, type: "resolved"},
    {source:4041, target: 3657, type: "resolved"},
    {source:4041, target: 2569, type: "resolved"},

    {source:3785, target: 2057, type: "licensing"},
    {source:3785, target: 3593, type: "resolved"},
    {source:3785, target: 3657, type: "resolved"},
    {source:3785, target: 2569, type: "resolved"},

    {source:2056, target: 3080, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576643, target: 1576899, type: "licensing"},
    {source:1576643, target: 1576675, type: "resolved"},

    {source:1777635, target: 2056163, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1777635, target: 2039779, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1777635, target: 2064355, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1015755, target: 12235, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2064329, target: 4041, type: "resolved"},
    {source:2064329, target: 12233, type: "licensing"},
    {source:2064329, target: 1015753, type: "resolved"},

    {source:12233, target: 4041, type: "licensing"},

    {source:3593, target: 2057, type: "licensing"},

    {source:3657, target: 2057, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576131, target: 1576899, type: "resolved"},
    {source:1576131, target: 1576643, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2056163, target: 2064355, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1015753, target: 4041, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2569, target: 2057, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1051660, target: 1575948, type: "licensing"},

    {source:2097097, target: 2064329, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1576675, target: 1576931, type: "licensing"},

    {source:1575944, target: 1575946, type: "licensing"}

];

var nodes = {};
let i = 0;

links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 1280,
    height = 1024;


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(100)
    .charge(-700)
    .chargeDistance(-700)
    .gravity(0.4)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

// Width and height of the svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Append arrows to indicate the direction of the processes 
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

// List of all object-nodes that are active
var activeNodes = force.nodes().filter(d => test.includes(d.name))


// Append the circles that demonstrate the processes
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        if (d.name === 9 | d.name === 2057) {
            return 15;
        } else {
             return 10;
        }
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        if (d.name === 9 | d.name === 2057){
                return '5.2px';}    
        })
    .call(force.drag);

// Append the Process-ID in numbers
var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick(d) {
    var index = 0
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
    circle.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (activeNodes.includes(d)){
                return 'green';}    
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(4000)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (activeNodes.includes(d)){
                return "#9B9798";}
        })
}

function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

At the moment im facing the problem with animation. I'm unable to figure out how to prevent all relevant objects to change the color at the same time.

My questions are:

- How to animate nodes independently
- How to continue the animation loop when the last object is reached

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Why are you using D3v3? Why `map` and then `filter` when `filter` alone is enough? Why create 3 identical markers? You want to color independent of the force simulation so why do the coloring inside the `tick`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm fairly new to JS and the library D3, so try to bear with me 1). D3v3 was blindly chosen. If this is the wrong library in fiddle, I'm sorry. After I selected it, fiddle showed everything the way it looks locally. 2). the map and filter combination was unnecessary, I admit to that. 3). What do you mean by 3 identical markers? I have one for each component of the visualisation (path, text and circle)?  4.) Correct, so I have to remove the transition from the tick and write a new function?

Comment: D3v3 is years old and not maintained any more, best to port the simulation to D3v5, read d3-force docs, not that difficult to port. You have 3 identical defs markers for arrows. Animate the color in a separate function and use `transition.on("end",....)`